# LoadError: no such file to load -- net/smtp

Tags: logstash

warning: thread "[main]-pipeline-manager" terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
LoadError: no such file to load -- net/smtp
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1057
module:Mail at C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail.rb:9
 at C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail.rb:3
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1057
register at C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/logstash-output-email-4.1.2/lib/logstash/outputs/email.rb:101
register at org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.java:69
register_plugins at C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:237
each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1987
register_plugins at C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:236
maybe_setup_out_plugins at C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:610
start_workers at C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:249
run at C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:194
start at C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:146
[2023-09-28T16:06:29,895][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
[2023-09-28T16:06:29,908][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (LoadError) no such file to load -- net/smtp
org.jruby.exceptions.LoadError: (LoadError) no such file to load -- net/smtp
at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1057) ~[jruby.jar:?]
at RUBY.module:Mail(C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail.rb:9) ~[?:?]
at RUBY.(C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail.rb:3) ~[?:?]
at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1057) ~[jruby.jar:?]
at RUBY.register(C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/logstash-output-email-4.1.2/lib/logstash/outputs/email.rb:101) ~[?:?]
at org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.register(org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.java:69) ~[logstash-core.jar:?]
at RUBY.register_plugins(C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:237) ~[?:?]
at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1987) ~[jruby.jar:?]
at RUBY.register_plugins(C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:236) ~[?:?]
at RUBY.maybe_setup_out_plugins(C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:610) ~[?:?]
at RUBY.start_workers(C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:249) ~[?:?]
at RUBY.run(C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:194) ~[?:?]
at RUBY.start(C:/elk/logstash-8.10.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:146) ~[?:?]
im getting this error can anyone?

i have tried to install bundle but it didnt work out

Comment: Please take your time to format your message properly

Answer (score 0):

It seems a [known bug fixed upstream](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-email/issues/68), current workaround is uninstalling `logstash-input-imap` and forcing `logstash-output-email` to version 4.1.3:

```
${YOUR_LOGSTASH_PATH}/bin/logstash-plugin remove logstash-input-imap
${YOUR_LOGSTASH_PATH}/bin/logstash-plugin install --version 4.1.3 logstash-output-email
```